# Push a python dataframe to Smartsheet using Smartsheet API

Tags: python, smartsheet-api, meraki-api

I have a python script where I'm trying to fetch data from meraki dashboard through its API. Now the data is stored in a dataframe which needs to be pushed to a Smartsheet using the Smartsheet API integration. I've tried searching the Smartsheet API documentation but couldn't find any solution to the problem. Has anyone worked on this kind of use case before or know a script to push a simple data frame to the smartsheet?

The code is something like this:

```py
for device in list_of_devices:
        
        try:
            dict1 = {'Name': [device['name']],
                "Serial_No": [device['serial']],
                'MAC': [device['mac']],
                'Network_Id': [device['networkId']],
                'Product_Type': [device['productType']],
                'Model': [device['model']],
                'Tags': [device['tags']],
                'Lan_Ip': [device['lanIp']],
                'Configuration_Updated_At': [device['configurationUpdatedAt']],
                'Firmware': [device['firmware']],
                'URL': [device['url']]
                }
        except KeyError:
            dict1['Lan_Ip'] = "NA"

        temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)
        alldata = alldata.append(temp)

alldata.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

The dataframe("alldata") looks something like this:

```
             Name       Serial_No                MAC  \
```

0    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
1    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

the dataframe has somewhere around 1000 rows and 11 columns

I've tried pushing this dataframe similar to the code mentioned in the comments but I'm getting a "Bad Request" error.

```py
smart = smartsheet.Smartsheet(access_token='xxxxxxxx')
sheet_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxx
sheet = smart.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)

column_map = {}
for column in sheet.columns:
    column_map[column.title] = column.id

data_dict = alldata.to_dict('index')


rowsToAdd = []
for i,i in data_dict.items():
    new_row = smart.models.Row()
    new_row.to_top = True


    for k,v in i.items():

        new_cell = smart.models.Cell()
        new_cell.column_id = column_map[k]
        new_cell.value = v
        
        new_row.cells.append(new_cell)

    rowsToAdd.append(new_row)

result = smart.Sheets.add_rows(sheet_id, rowsToAdd)

{"response": {"statusCode": 400, "reason": "Bad Request", "content": {"detail": {"index": 0}, "errorCode": 1012, "message": "Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: cell.value.", "refId": "1ob56acvz5nzv"}}}
```

[Smartsheet photo where the data must be pushed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwVW5.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas DataFrame to Smartsheet sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72378028/pandas-dataframe-to-smartsheet-sheet)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code adds data from a dataframe to a sheet in Smartsheet -- this should be enough to at least get you started. If you still can't get the desired result using this code, please update your original post to include the code you're using, the outcome you're wanting, and a detailed description of the issue you encountered. (Add a comment to this answer if you update your original post, so I'll be notified and will know to look.)

```
# target sheet
sheet_id = 3932034054809476
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)

# translate column names to column id
column_map = {}
for column in sheet.columns:
    column_map[column.title] = column.id

df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': [111111, 222222],
                'item_color': ['red', 'yellow'],
                'item_location': ['office', 'kitchen']})

data_dict = df.to_dict('index')

rowsToAdd = []

# each object in data_dict represents 1 row of data
for i, i in data_dict.items():

    # create a new row object
    new_row = smartsheet_client.models.Row()
    new_row.to_top = True

    # for each key value pair, create & add a cell to the row object
    for k, v in i.items():

        # create the cell object and populate with value
        new_cell = smartsheet_client.models.Cell()
        new_cell.column_id = column_map[k]
        new_cell.value = v

        # add the cell object to the row object
        new_row.cells.append(new_cell)

    # add the row object to the collection of rows
    rowsToAdd.append(new_row)

# add the collection of rows to the sheet in Smartsheet         
result = smartsheet_client.Sheets.add_rows(sheet_id, rowsToAdd)
```

**UPDATE #1 - re `Bad Request` error**

Seems like the error you've described in your first comment below is perhaps being caused by the fact that some of the cells in your dataframe don't have a value. When you add a new row using the Smartsheet API, each cell that's specified for the row must specify a `value` for the cell -- otherwise you'll get the `Bad Request` error you've described. Maybe try adding an `if` statement inside the `for` loop to skip adding the cell if the value of `v` is `None`?

```
for k,v in i.items():

    # skip adding this cell if there's no value
    if v is None:
        continue

   ...
```

**UPDATE #2 - re further troubleshooting**

In response to your second comment below: you'll need to debug further using the data in your dataframe, as I'm unable to repro the issue you describe using other data.

To simplify things -- I'd suggest that you start by trying to debug with just one item in the dataframe. You can do so by adding the line (statement) `break` at the end of the `for` loop that's building the `dict` -- that way, only the first device will be added.

```
for device in list_of_devices:
        
    try:
        ...
    except KeyError:
        dict1['Lan_Ip'] = "NA"

    temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)
    alldata = alldata.append(temp)

    # break out of loop after one item is added
    break

alldata.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# print dataframe contents
print (alldata)
```

If you get the same error when testing with just one item, and can't recognize what it is about that data (or the way it's stored in your dataframe) that's causing the Smartsheet error, then feel free to add a `print (alldata)` statement after the `for` loop (as I show in the code snippet above) to your code and update your original post again to include the output of that statement (changing any sensitive data values, of course) -- and then I can try to repro/troubleshoot using that data.

**UPDATE #3 - repro'd issue**

Okay, so I've reproduced the error you've described -- by specifying `None` as the value of a field in the dict.

The following code successfully inserts two new rows into Smartsheet -- because every field in each dict it builds contains a (non-`None`) value. (For simplicity, I'm manually constructing two dicts in the same manner as you do in your `for` loop.)

```
# target sheet
sheet_id = 37558492129156
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)

# translate column names to column id
column_map = {}
for column in sheet.columns:
    column_map[column.title] = column.id

#----
# start: repro SO question's building of dataframe
#----

alldata = pd.DataFrame()

dict1 = {'Name': ['name1'],
    "Serial_No": ['serial_no1'],
    'MAC': ['mac1'],
    'Network_Id': ['networkId1'],
    'Product_Type': ['productType1'],
    'Model': ['model1'],
    'Tags': ['tags1'],
    'Lan_Ip': ['lanIp1'],
    'Configuration_Updated_At': ['configurationUpdatedAt1'],
    'Firmware': ['firmware1'],
    'URL': ['url1']
    }
    
temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)
alldata = alldata.append(temp)

dict2 = {'Name': ['name2'],
    "Serial_No": ['serial_no2'],
    'MAC': ['mac2'],
    'Network_Id': ['networkId2'],
    'Product_Type': ['productType2'],
    'Model': ['model2'],
    'Tags': ['tags2'],
    'Lan_Ip': ['lanIp2'],
    'Configuration_Updated_At': ['configurationUpdatedAt2'],
    'Firmware': ['firmware2'],
    'URL': ['URL2']
    }
    
temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict2)
alldata = alldata.append(temp)

alldata.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

#----
# end: repro SO question's building of dataframe
#----

data_dict = alldata.to_dict('index')

rowsToAdd = []

# each object in data_dict represents 1 row of data
for i, i in data_dict.items():

    # create a new row object
    new_row = smartsheet_client.models.Row()
    new_row.to_top = True

    # for each key value pair, create & add a cell to the row object
    for k, v in i.items():

        # create the cell object and populate with value
        new_cell = smartsheet_client.models.Cell()
        new_cell.column_id = column_map[k]
        new_cell.value = v

        # add the cell object to the row object
        new_row.cells.append(new_cell)

    # add the row object to the collection of rows
    rowsToAdd.append(new_row)

result = smartsheet_client.Sheets.add_rows(sheet_id, rowsToAdd)
```

However, running the following code (where the value of the `URL` field in the second dict is set to `None`) results in the same error you've described:

```
{"response": {"statusCode": 400, "reason": "Bad Request", "content": {"detail": {"index": 1}, "errorCode": 1012, "message": "Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: cell.value.", "refId": "dw1id3oj1bv0"}}}
```

Code that causes this error (identical to the successful code above except that the value of the `URL` field in the second dict is `None`):

```
# target sheet
sheet_id = 37558492129156
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)

# translate column names to column id
column_map = {}
for column in sheet.columns:
    column_map[column.title] = column.id

#----
# start: repro SO question's building of dataframe
#----
alldata = pd.DataFrame()

dict1 = {'Name': ['name1'],
    "Serial_No": ['serial_no1'],
    'MAC': ['mac1'],
    'Network_Id': ['networkId1'],
    'Product_Type': ['productType1'],
    'Model': ['model1'],
    'Tags': ['tags1'],
    'Lan_Ip': ['lanIp1'],
    'Configuration_Updated_At': ['configurationUpdatedAt1'],
    'Firmware': ['firmware1'],
    'URL': ['url1']
    }
    
temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)
alldata = alldata.append(temp)

dict2 = {'Name': ['name2'],
    "Serial_No": ['serial_no2'],
    'MAC': ['mac2'],
    'Network_Id': ['networkId2'],
    'Product_Type': ['productType2'],
    'Model': ['model2'],
    'Tags': ['tags2'],
    'Lan_Ip': ['lanIp2'],
    'Configuration_Updated_At': ['configurationUpdatedAt2'],
    'Firmware': ['firmware2'],
    'URL': [None]
    }
    
temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict2)
alldata = alldata.append(temp)

alldata.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

#----
# end: repro SO question's building of dataframe
#----

data_dict = alldata.to_dict('index')

rowsToAdd = []

# each object in data_dict represents 1 row of data
for i, i in data_dict.items():

    # create a new row object
    new_row = smartsheet_client.models.Row()
    new_row.to_top = True

    # for each key value pair, create & add a cell to the row object
    for k, v in i.items():

        # create the cell object and populate with value
        new_cell = smartsheet_client.models.Cell()
        new_cell.column_id = column_map[k]
        new_cell.value = v

        # add the cell object to the row object
        new_row.cells.append(new_cell)

    # add the row object to the collection of rows
    rowsToAdd.append(new_row)

result = smartsheet_client.Sheets.add_rows(sheet_id, rowsToAdd)
```

Finally, note that the error message I received contains `{"index": 1}` -- this implies that the value of `index` in this error message indicates the (zero-based) index of the problematic row. The fact that your error message contains `{"index": 0}` implies that there's a problem with the data in the first row you're trying to add to Smartsheet (i.e., the first item in the dataframe). Therefore, following the troubleshooting guidance I posted in my previous update (**Update #2** above) should allow you to closely examine the data for the first item/row and hopefully spot the problematic data (i.e., where the value is missing).

Comment: I've made changes to the original post. I tried replicating your code for my use case but I'm getting a 400 BadRequest
{"response": {"statusCode": 400, "reason": "Bad Request", "content": {"detail": {"index": 0}, "errorCode": 1012, "message": "Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: cell.value.", "refId": "1ob56acvz5nzv"}}}

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've updated my answer with more information (**UPDATE re `Bad Request` error**).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I made the changes as you suggested and the same error pops up. I checked my dataframe by pushing the data to excel. Turns out there is no cell in it which is having a "None" value. Also as per the error "{"response": {"statusCode": 400, "reason": "Bad Request", "content": {"detail": {"index": 0}, "errorCode": 1012, "message": "Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: cell.value.", "refId": "1w51mxxjh7mn3"}}}", 

Seems like the index:0 tells that the loop is not taking the first value from the first dataframe cell itself

Comment: Okay, let's simplify your troubleshooting process by testing with just one item. I've updated my answer with more info (**UPDATE #2 - re further troubleshooting**).

Comment: I was finally able to repro the issue you've described. See **UPDATE #3 - repro'd issue** in my answer for details.

Comment: Hi Kim, I've made the changes based on your updates and did some troubleshooting from my end as well and the code is working fine now. Thanks a ton for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the update --glad to hear you've got it working! If you're willing to share a high-level description of what was causing the problem, others may be able to benefit from that info in the future. (Feel free to just add that info as a comment here.) Thanks again for the update!